# Trello get cards API corrupts links in the text

Tags: trello, trelloapi

I made a script for extracting info from Trello using Tello API and python (requests library).
After some time, Trello Added more text and links formatting options (like inline, card, emmbed, etc.) and I started updating my script to parse that type of links as well.
But now I can see what Trello's [Get Cards API](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/trello/rest/api-group-boards/#api-boards-id-cards-get) call returns some links with additional single or double `\` sign. Usually in Google Docs ID part (`14s\_pSDXAmRsljfjpiKLZTWOjWNYFdO0d` instead of `14s_pSDXAmRsljfjpiKLZTWOjWNYFdO0d` ). Why does it happened, who's fault is it and what to do? Is it safe enough to blindly remove `\` signs from the link? (even Stack Overflow automatically removed it from my text lol, until I put it to the code section)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I will answer on myown question.
So, it seems after Trello [updated](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Trello-articles/New-Editor-in-Trello/ba-p/2038725) it's markdown, some symbols can be used for markdow syntax and in the text as well. So to avoid sudden mixup between regular text and syntax, trello escaping that symbols. For example, "_" will be replaced with "_" so Trello could understand it's not the beginning or ending of the italic text.
That's my assumption, but it seems like the only one logic explanation.